# Creating List of nested class in Python

Tags: python, class, nested

I'm trying to create an Hierarchical data structure with nested classes.
I have a file that has several NET's and each NET has several PORT's.
So I want to go over the file in one swap and collect all data at once.
I tried the following code:

```
        """Parent Class to all PORTS children classes"""
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
            self.port = Net.Port(x_cord = None)
            
        def display(self):
            print("Inside Net Display")
            print("Net name:",self.name)
        
        def reveal(self):
            ## Calling the inner class Port
            self.port.port_display("Calling inner class Port from outer class Net")
            
        def show_classes(self):
            print("Net class:", self.display())
            print("Port class:",self.port.display())
            
        class Port:
            """Inner class in Net class"""
            def __init__(self, x_cord):
                self.x_cord = x_cord
                
            def display(self):
                print("Inside Port display")
                print(self.x_cord)
```

So now I create the NET class and the port instances:

```
net_0 = Net("Net_10")
port_0 = net_0.port
port_1 = net_0.port

# initializing port_0 
port_0.x_cord = 5
port_0.display()
# output:
Inside Port display
5
# when looking at port_1 i see that it is the same as port_0
port_1.display()
Inside Port display
5
```

what actually happened is that I created two port instances, but they were the same one.
port_0
<**main**.Net.Port at 0x27649b40d60>
port_1
<**main**.Net.Port at 0x27649b40d60>

how can I create two different sub cells of port?

thanks,
GB

Comment: Why are you nesting the class? What advantage does that give you?

Comment: "# when looking at port_1 i see that it is the same as port_0" well, *of course it is*. You only ever create a single `Net.Port` instance... inside the `__init__` of `Net`, which you instantiate here: `net_0 = Net("Net_10")`. Then, you simply assign that instance to two different names, `port_0` and `port_1`.

Comment: Well, I started with nested Dictionary but it went complicated. my desire is to create the hierarchical DB as I pass over the file. I have a bout 3M line in  a file, so I don't want to go over it again & again with each loop for every NEt and PORT's within it. I thought that if I create an obj for each NET and then OBJ's for each PORT, I will succeed to capture all instances in one sweep. If you can suggest on another way, you are more then welcome (-:

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I'm asking why are you nesting the `Port` class inside the `Net` class? That doesn't make any sense. Just bring `Port` outside into the same level as `Net`.

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I 'm open to ideas...I appreciate your effort.  I tried to eliminate the nested part and as you mentioned here, I generated two classes that solve the issue.  The code is very short and I was leaning on a similar solution from: GerryDevine , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057560/initialising-nested-classes-in-python. Thanks for the help (-: